# Java : UI thread not resuming in two-threaded application

Tags: java, multithreading, bluetooth

I'm currently building a Java application using two threads :

The first thread is about the UI of the application, and also the processing of command received via the bluetooth thread.

The bluetooth thread is bluetooth server waiting for a robot to connect and handling communication.

As of now, the UI thread is in wait() state until the bluetooth thread gets a new message to process.

The problem is, I can trace the notify/notifyAll call from the bluetooth thread, but my UI is not resuming it's activity.

I am now sure I misunderstood something about the proper way to manage synchronized threads, but I can't figure out what's wrong in my software.

Here is the code for the UI :

```
package mapper;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class MapperUI extends JFrame implements Runnable {

private ArrayList<String> messageArray;

public MapperUI(){
        super();        
        build();
        this.setVisible(true);
        new Thread(this).start();
}

private void build(){
    setTitle("SLAM Mapper");
    setSize(600,500);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setContentPane(buildContentPane());
}   
private JPanel buildContentPane(){
    JPanel main = new JPanel();
    main.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    //TODO Implements auto-generated map after bluetooth communication
    MapPanel map = new MapPanel();
    main.add(map,BorderLayout.CENTER);

    //TODO This fields will be buildt with stored message
    JTable positions = new JTable(15,2);
    main.add(positions,BorderLayout.EAST);

    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    JButton bouton = new JButton("Start");
    buttonPanel.add(bouton);

    JButton bouton2 = new JButton("Send");
    buttonPanel.add(bouton2);

    main.add(buttonPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    return main;
}

public synchronized void run(){
    MapperCom bt = new MapperCom();
    while(true){
        try {
            System.out.println("Mapper is Waiting......");
            wait();
            String message = bt.getMessage();
            this.messageArray.add(message);
            bt.setNextCommand(processMessage(message));
            notifyAll();
            System.out.println("Mapper Notify");
            build();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
}

public String processMessage(String message){
    String command = "";
    //TODO Build a response
    command = "fffff\n";
    return command;
}
}
```

Here is the bluetoothService :

```
package mapper;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.bluetooth.DiscoveryAgent;
import javax.bluetooth.LocalDevice;
import javax.bluetooth.UUID;
import javax.microedition.io.Connector;
import javax.microedition.io.StreamConnection;
import javax.microedition.io.StreamConnectionNotifier;

public class MapperCom extends Thread {
public final UUID uuid = new UUID(                              
        "27012f0c68af4fbf8dbe6bbaf7aa432a", false);
public final String name = "Server";                       
public final String url  =  "btspp://localhost:" + uuid         
                            + ";name=" + name 
                            + ";authenticate=false;encrypt=false;";
private LocalDevice local ;
private StreamConnectionNotifier server ;
private StreamConnection conn ;
private DataInputStream din ;
private DataOutputStream dout ;

private String command;
private String message;

public MapperCom(){
     try {
        this.command = "";
        this.message = "";

        System.out.println("Setting device to be discoverable...");
        local = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice();
        local.setDiscoverable(DiscoveryAgent.GIAC);
        System.out.println("Start advertising service...");

        server = (StreamConnectionNotifier)Connector.open(url);
        System.out.println("Waiting for incoming connection...\n");

        conn = server.acceptAndOpen();
        System.out.println("Client Connected...");
        din = new DataInputStream(conn.openInputStream());
        dout = new DataOutputStream(conn.openOutputStream());

        new Thread(this).start();

        } catch (Exception  e) {
            System.out.println("Exception Occured: " + e.toString());
        }
}

@Override
public synchronized void run(){
    System.out.println("Bluetooth Thread Started");
    while(true){
        try {
            String cmd = "";
            char c;
            System.out.println("Waiting for message");
            while (((c = din.readChar()) > 0) && (c!='\n') ){
                System.out.println("Char received :"+c);
                cmd = cmd + c;
            }

            storeMessage(cmd);

            System.out.println("Bt Notify......");
            notifyAll();
            System.out.println("Bt is Waiting for a command from mapper......");
            wait();
            sendResponse();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void sendResponse(){
    try {
        dout.writeChars(command);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public synchronized String getMessage(){
    return this.message;
}

public synchronized void storeMessage (String data){
    this.message = data;
    System.out.println("Received " + data);
}
public synchronized int setNextCommand (String data){
    int result = -1;
    //TODO Implement proper protocol
    this.command = data;
    System.out.println("Sending " + data);

    return result;
}
}
```

Comment: Definitely never put the UI thread into wait state. This freezes your GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is one sample program. Basically there needs some common lock between 2 threads if you want communication using wait & notify.

```
package ravi.tutorial.java.threads;

public class TestThreads {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CommonLock commonLock = new CommonLock();
        Thread1 thread1 = new Thread1(commonLock);
        Thread2 thread2 = new Thread2(commonLock);
        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
    }
}

/*
 * Common monitor lock between both threads, used for communication using wait
 * notify.
 */
class CommonLock {

}

// Extending Thread instead of Runnable as its just a test
class Thread1 extends Thread {

    private CommonLock commonLock;

    public Thread1(CommonLock commonLock) {
        this.commonLock = commonLock;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Started thread 1");
        System.out.println("waiting thread 1");
        try {
            // TO wait on commonLock, first need to get lock on commonLock. SO
            // put synchronized block of commonLock.
            synchronized (commonLock) {
                commonLock.wait();
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("DONE waiting thread 1 as I got notification from THread 2");
    }

}

class Thread2 extends Thread {

    private CommonLock commonLock;

    public Thread2(CommonLock commonLock) {
        this.commonLock = commonLock;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Running thread 2");

        try {
            System.out.println("Sleeping thread 2");
            // Just take gap of 2 sec before notifying.
            Thread.sleep(2000);

            // TO notify on commonLock, first need to get lock on commonLock. SO
            // put synchronized block of commonLock.
            synchronized (commonLock) {
                System.out.println("Notifying thread 2");
                commonLock.notifyAll();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this complete implementation

Answer (score 5):

I think when you call `notifyAll()`, it calls `this.notifyAll()`. Which there are no other elements waiting in the same class. So what you can do is you share the same object over both classes and call `obj.wait()` and `obj.notifyAll()`. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this: [Thread tutorial](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=306)

> - wait( ) tells the calling thread to give up the monitor and go to
>   sleep until some other  thread enters the same monitor and calls
>   notify( ).
> - notify( ) wakes up the first thread that called wait( ) on
>   the same object.
> - notifyAll( ) wakes up all the threads that called    wait( ) on the
>   same object. The  highest priority thread will run    first.

This is main misunderstanding of thread conception in Java.